# Accessing child objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

'tI am extending two JavaScript objects where one is a variable ajaxed in from a file and the other is a simple object with user preferences.

```
// local prefs
var prefs = { name: "Bob Barker", show: "Price is Right" };

// ajax in default prefs with dataType: "script"
var defaultPrefs = { 
         studio: { name: "CBS", location: "Hollywood, CA" },
         producers: [ { name: "Producer1" }, { name: "Producer2" } ]
}

// merge prefs
var mergedPrefs = $.extend( prefs, defaultPrefs );
```

The problem is I can't access the producers or studio using prefs.producers or prefs.studio as they are Objects in the merged file. How can I get around this?

Comment: Are you saying you *want* to be able to access them using `prefs.producers` or that you *do not want* to access them using `prefs.producers`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var mergedPrefs = $.extend({}, prefs, defaultPrefs);
```

Extending an empty object will create a new copy of the original object(s).

You can also use `Object.assign` for the same task, however `jQuery.extend` also has a *deep option* to merge recursively whereas `Object.assign` is always flat (for better performance).

Comment: @MoreScratch This answer seems to do what you want, but also note that you don't need to use jQuery for this. You can also use the ES6 `Object.assign` function, which is functionally equivalent to `$.extend`.

Comment: Taken from the docs: If, however, you want to preserve both of the original objects, you can do so by passing an empty object as the target:var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2); https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, but I recomend [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) in ES6 to don't use JQuery. Is the same:

```
var mergedPrefs = Object.assign({}, prefs, defaultPrefs);
```

Snippet with your code working without Object.assign (using `$.extend`):

```js
// local prefs
var prefs = {
  name: "Bob Barker",
  show: "Price is Right"
};

// ajax in default prefs with dataType: "script"
var defaultPrefs = {
  studio: {
    name: "CBS",
    location: "Hollywood, CA"
  },
  producers: [{
    name: "Producer1"
  }, {
    name: "Producer2"
  }]
}

// merge prefs
var mergedPrefs = $.extend({}, prefs, defaultPrefs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: AS ECMA Script 6th edition, you may provide a polypill for browsers that don't support ES6. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign